# Plot data returned from groupby function in Pandas using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

So I am using the groupby function in pandas to get mean of two columns using conditions based on two other columns. I am having trouble creating the matplotlib plots

An example table is

```
data_temp = pd.DataFrame([
        [3, 16, 0, 0, 10],
        [3, 20, 0, 1, 11],
        [3, 25, 0, 2, 11],
        [3, 30, 0, 3, 15],
        [4, 30, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 45, 0, 1, 0],
        [4, 54, 0, 2, 0],
        [4, 54, 0, 3, 0],
        [5, 31, 0, 0, 14],
        [5, 32, 0, 1, 15],
        [5, 45, 0, 2, 0],
        [5, 46, 0, 3, 0],
        [3, 1, 0, 0, 11],
        [3, 5, 0, 1, 12],
        [3, 6, 0, 2, 13],
        [3, 8, 0, 3, 11],
        [4, 35, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 25, 0, 1, 0],
        [4, 34, 0, 2, 0],
        [4, 24, 0, 3, 0]
    ], columns=list('ABCDE'))


result = data_temp.groupby(['A', 'D']).agg({'B':'mean', 'E':'mean'})
print(result)
```

I get

```
        B     E
A D            
3 0   8.5  10.5
  1  12.5  11.5
  2  15.5  12.0
  3  19.0  13.0
4 0  32.5   0.0
  1  35.0   0.0
  2  44.0   0.0
  3  39.0   0.0
5 0  31.0  14.0
  1  32.0  15.0
  2  45.0   0.0
  3  46.0   0.0
```

​
Now I am trying to plot the data where x axis = A y axis = B mean  and I have 4 plots one for each D value

Similarly a plot for E mean on a separate plot

I tried a couple of things but the main issue I face is groupby
creates a hash table like structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unstack` on result:

```
result2 = result.unstack()
reuslt2
```

[image]

Then `B.plot()`

```
result2.B.plot()
```

[image]

And `E.plot()`

```
result2.E.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm. Just a followup. How do I enable minor ticks in this plot. I don't see an option in pandas library. Also is there a way to not show them as i am trying to save them to a file using plt.savefig

Comment: I don't know off top of my head, but I'm sure there are plenty of SO question/answers for it already

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

data = A.groupby(['D','A'])['E','B'].mean().reset_index()

#For the plot of B vs A
fig, ax = pp.subplots()
for value, groups in data.groupby('D'):
     ax.plot(group.A,group.B)
pp.show()
```

Comment: Hi that just plotted one mode to the plot.. Not sure why